How to remove extreme outlier from extracted topology in `pc-skeletor` and Open3d?
I’m working with a point cloud dataset and extracting its skeleton and topology using pc_skeletor and visualizing it with Open3D. However, upon extracting the topology from pc_skeletor's lbc.topology, I am encountering an extreme outlier, as shown in the images below. I am 100% sure that the point cloud doesn't have any outlier at the point where the outlier edge (blue line) is located.

Image 1: The coordinate frame represents the origin. The blue line marks the outlier edge of the topology, while the red circled region is where the actual point cloud is located.


Image 2: A zoomed-in view of the point cloud where most of the data is actually located.


Image 3: The original point cloud for reference.



I would like to remove this extreme outlier from the topology. My question is:

Is there any part of the codebase that could be generating this outlier, or is this due to an issue in the topology extraction process?
How can I remove or handle this outlier efficiently?

Here’s the part of my current code responsible for point cloud processing and topology extraction:
import open3d as o3d
import numpy as np
from pc_skeletor import Dataset, LBC

# Load point cloud
pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud("input.xyz")
cl, ind = pcd.remove_statistical_outlier(nb_neighbors=20, std_ratio=2.0)

inlier_cloud = pcd.select_by_index(ind)

# Initialize LBC for skeleton extraction
lbc = LBC(point_cloud=inlier_cloud, down_sample=0.008)
print('Point cloud loaded')

# Skeleton and topology extraction
lbc.extract_skeleton()
print('Skeleton extracted')
lbc.extract_topology()
print('Topology extracted')

# Visualization of the topology
# Coordinate frame at the origin
coordinate_frame = o3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.create_coordinate_frame(size=100.0, origin=[0, 0, 0])

o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([coordinate_frame, lbc.topology])

